# How do I keep text selected when changing from Visual to Insert mode?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I am running Vim extension in VS Code and want to be able to select text using Visual mode and keep that text selected when I'm in Insert mode. Currently I am able to select text in Visual mode but the selection becomes unselected when I change to Insert mode. Is this possible?

Comment: Define "keep selected". What should happen if you select a text and change something inside of it? Also, maybe you can find it useful to select, do whatever changes you need and then use `gv` to re-highlight the last selection.

Answer (score 1):

In Vim, you can only be in one mode; so it's either insert mode *or* visual mode. That said, Vim remembers the start, end, and type of the previous selection, and it can be easily reselected via `gv` (cp. [`:help reselect-Visual`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#reselect-Visual)).

As Vim has special atoms to specify mark positions in a regular expression ([`:help /\%'m`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25%27m)), and the `'<` and `'>` marks correspond to the current selection, we can use `:match` to make the last (characterwise) selection permanently visible:

```
:match Visual /\%'<\_.*\%'>\_./
```